# Remove lines between special characters in Unix

Tags: awk, sed, grep, string

In my code/text file whatever is between `/*` and `*/` is commented - 
I have to remove this commented code from my text/code file

```
$ cat codefile.txt
/*~BB~*************************************
asdasd
asdas
asdasd
asdas
asdad
*************************************/

/*
aasdas
asdsa
asdsa
*/
```

But when I use:

```
sed -i '/^\/\*/,/*\*\//d'
```

it only deletes lines where I only have one star after/before the slash - the second block I mean.

How can I get rid of the first one ?

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine (on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`)

Answer (score 1):

Use below command it worked fine for me I tested by inserting other contents in file too. it only deletes the lines which is between /* and */

---

```
sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d' filename
```

---